# Spring MVC: маппинг таблицы БД через XML

Tags: java, mvc, hibernate, jpa

Всем доброго дня! Возникла задача, над решением которой уже сломал весь мозг. Досталось "в наследство" небольшое веб-приложение на Java: оно лезет в одну-единственную таблицу в БД и определённым образом выводит её содержимое на страничку JSP.

Возникла необходимость смены таблицы, при этом структура таблицы остаётся неизменной, меняются лишь содержимое и имя таблицы. На данный момент имя таблицы указывается в коде сущности с помощью аннотации (`@Table(name = "megatable")`), и хотелось бы как-то замаппить его в xml-файле, чтобы каждый раз не хардкодить аннотацию и не пересобирать приложение. Изрядно погуглив и начитавшись всякого, сделал два xml-файла: orm.xml (в нём описывается сущность, в которую должна отображаться таблица) и persistence.xml, где, по идее, этот файл и маппится - однако ничего не работает

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "textilentity" does not exist

Видимо, неправильно замаппил. Возможно, эта проблема решается просто и стандартно, однако я только начинаю осваивать данные технологии, и пока что не могу придумать ничего помимо того, что написал выше.

Вот мой файл orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm    
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<description>Quiz Table Mapping</description>
<package>ru.yradio</package> 
<entity class="ru.yradio.TextilEntity" name="TextilEntity">        
    <table name="megatable"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="TABLE"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="date">
            <column name="date"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="answer_status">
            <column name="answer_status"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="callerid">
            <column name="callerid"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="prize">
            <column name="prize"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="prize_taken">
            <column name="prize_taken"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Вот файл persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="entityManager">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <mapping-file>\META-INF\orm.xml</mapping-file> 
    <class>ru.esound.TextilEntity</class>
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

И вот на всякий случай - файл application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder order="0" location="classpath:config/application.properties"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location" value="classpath:config/application.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>ru.yradio</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"></prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.yradio"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="ru.yradio" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManager"/>
```

Файлы orm.xml и persistence.xml лежат у меня в META-INF проекта, application.xml - в WEB-INF.
Настройки доступа к БД вынесены в отдельный конфиг-файл. С маппингом таблицы через аннотацию всё работает, а так, как сделал я - нет. Очень хочется понять, что я делаю не так, и как всё-таки нужно. В сети информации много, но практически вся она обрывочна и привязана к конкретным проектам. А мне важно понять общие принципы действия.
Буду благодарен любой помощи, советам, рекомендациям!

UPD. Стектрейс:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "textilentity" не  существует
Position: 228
   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2116)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1899)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:567)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:436)
com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:197)
com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:249)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.executeSorted(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:209)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:119)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:49)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:434)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:419)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:391)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy459.findAll(Unknown Source)
ru.yradio.TextilService.selectAll(TextilService.java:24)
ru.yradio.TextilController.data(TextilController.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Класс-сущность TextilEntity (закомментированы аннотации, которые были в исходном коде - в т.ч. и аннотация @Table, которую, собственно, мне и нужно победить в XML).

```
@Entity
//@Table(name = "megatable")

public class TextilEntity {
//@Column(name = "id")
@Id
private Long id;

//@Column(name = "date")
private String date;

//@Column(name = "answer_status")
private Boolean answer_status;

//@Column(name = "callerid")
private String callerid;

//@Column(name = "prize")
private String prize;

//@Column(name = "prize_taken")
private String prize_taken;

//геттеры и сеттеры
```

Код с запросом (интерфейс TextilRepository расширяет JpaRepository, и, таким образом, запросы выполняются с помощью CRUD-методов, реализованных в JpaRepository):

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TextilService {
@Autowired
private TextilRepository repository;

public Iterable<TextilEntity> selectAll(){
    QTextilEntity textilEntity = QTextilEntity.textilEntity;
    Predicate prt=textilEntity.answer_status.eq(true);
    return repository.findAll(prt, new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));}

...
}
```

Comment: Ошибка идет от бд. В маппинге отражены зависимости к другим таблицам? Имя "textilentity" действительно верное? Оно написано в нужном регистре?

Comment: Других таблиц там просто нет. Та, на которую отображается сущность - одна-единственная (в xml-ке она значится как megatable). Что касается имени сущности, то везде в java-коде оно прописано как TextilEntity. В lowercase оно нигде не упоминается. Ещё и поэтому меня эта ошибка приводит в замешательство.

Comment: Заметил, убрал кривой ответ. Но я всетаки грешу на orm.xml на этот  name="TextilEntity">. В примерах его в обще не используют. Я так подозреваю что он тоже ссылается на имя таблицы(этакое сокращение). Попробуйте убрать этот атрибут.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте `TextilEntity` и код с запросом, который вы выполняете.

Comment: И вот это выглядит странно `<class>ru.esound.TextilEntity</class>`, куда это замаплено?

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

`<table name="megatable"/>`

соответствует

```
@Table(name = "megatable")
class TextilEntity {

}
```

`<entity class="ru.yradio.TextilEntity" name="TextilEntity">`

соответствует

```
@Entity(name = "TextilEntity")
class TextilEntity {

}
```

где `TextilEntity` имя таблицы в базе данных, если `@Table(name = "")` отсутствует.

То есть Вы используете два имени таблицы, заданные разными способами: `megatable`, `TextilEntity`. Вы не приводите полный stacktrace, поэтому не понятно, где ошибка: на этапе апдейта схемы, или на этапе выполнения запроса. В любом случае Hibernate пытается получить доступ к таблице БД, которой не существует.

Вот это не нужно, так как Вы указываете полное имя класса
`<package>ru.yradio</package>`

Таким образом, чтобы исправить ошибку, уберите атрибут `name`.

```
<entity class="ru.yradio.TextilEntity">        
    <table name="megatable"/>
    <attributes>
       ...
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

**Update**

У Вас остались аннотации `@Entity` и `@Id` их нужно удалить.

Вот это сканирует пакет для классов с аннотацией `@Entity`

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
  <list>
    <value>ru.yradio</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

возможно проблема в этом, это тоже надо удалить.

Не знаю вот это надо или нет
`<class>ru.esound.TextilEntity</class>`

`QTextilEntity textilEntity = QTextilEntity.textilEntity;`

Если это сгенерированный класс, возможно его надо пересоздать.